# Amethyst Rust: 'Cannot insert multiple systems with the same name ("parent_hierarchy_system") when running pong tutorial

Tags: rust, amethyst

I am learning Amethyst framework for Rust. And now I follow pong tutorial [here](https://book.amethyst.rs/stable/pong-tutorial.html).
On step 3 (Moving paddles) tutorial teaches how to set up `System` for moving paddles.
I followed all the steps, however when I `cargo run` my application i get an error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot insert multiple systems with the same name ("parent_hierarchy_system")', /home/path_to_cargo/shred-0.9.4/src/dispatch/builder.rs:172:17
```

I tried just to copy from GitHub repository of tutorial but get the same result.

My `Cargo.toml` looks:

```
[package]
name = "pong"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = []
edition = "2018"

[dependencies.amethyst]
version = "0.13"
features = ["vulkan"]
```

I run the project on Ubuntu 19.10.
Rust version 1.37.

My guess is that `input_system` is somehow added twice when running. I have searched both tutorial repository for the same issue and the web. But it seems I am the only one who faced it. Perhaps solution is very easy but I have spent my Saturday trying to fix it.

```
let game_data = GameDataBuilder::default()
    .with_bundle(TransformBundle::new())?
    .with_bundle(input_bundle)?
    .with(systems::PaddleSystem, "paddle_system", &["input_system"]) // Add this line
    .with_bundle(
        RenderingBundle::<DefaultBackend>::new()
            .with_plugin(
                RenderToWindow::from_config_path(display_config_path)
                    .with_clear([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]),
            )
            // RenderFlat2D plugin is used to render entities with a `SpriteRender` component.
            .with_plugin(RenderFlat2D::default()),
        )?
    .with_bundle(TransformBundle::new())?;
```

The code of my `GameDataBuilder` initialization.

Comment: Can you try `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run`? It will show you where the panic originates, which may also be the offending line.

Comment: @edwardw the error occurs after I have initialized `game_data` and then initialize application itself `let mut game = Application::new(assets_dir, Pong, game_data)?;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the `TransformBundle` twice.

Removing one will remove this error.